# Solving a simple trig equation: $12 \sin^2 (x)+ \cos(x)=11$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem asks to determine all solutions to the equation $12 \sin^2 (x)+ \cos(x)=11$ over the interval $[0,2\pi)$.  Seems straightforward to me but I was marked wrong and it's important I understand why and the only explanation I get is I should have added $\pi$.  I need a better math explanation than that.

I replaced $\sin^2x$ with $1-\cos^2x$.  This yields:  $-12 \cos^2x + \cos x +1=0$.  Multiplying thru by $-1$ I get $12 \cos^2x-\cos x -1=0$.  This yields $\cos x=1/3 $ and $\cos x=-1/4$.

Now here's the part I was marked wrong on.  Since they want the answers in radians I simply took (in radian mode) the inverse cosine of $1/3$.  This yielded $x=1.231$. I examined that same reference angle in quadrant 4 (the other place where cosine is positive).  So, I did $2\pi-1.231=5.052$.  Counted totally wrong.

I did the same thing for inverse cosine of $-1/4$; I got $x=1.82$ and $x=4.46$  Counted totally wrong.

***YET***... when I plug these values back into the original equation it does equal $11$.  I don't understand where I went wrong.

Comment: Added $\pi$ to ***what*** exactly? I'm not sure what's wrong with your method (it even generates all four solutions, which one can verify by graphing), nor am I sure what adding $\pi$ to ***anything*** here would achieve. It would only serve to turn Quadrant I angles to Quadrant III, and Quadrant IV angles to Quadrant II, but cosine is negative in those quadrants.

Comment: Were you supposed to give approximate solutions or exact solutions?

Comment: You'll probably need to ask your teacher/grader.

Comment: @PrincessEev The range of the $\cos^{-1}(x)$ function is $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi.$  Given the constraints of the problem, and given that $\cos(\theta) = \cos(2\pi - \theta)$, the original poster did exactly the right thing.  The answer should have been marked as correct by the teacher.   ...see next comment

Comment: The only issue is whether the problem had specified that you were required to provide numerical answers, correct to three decimal places.  The exact answers, which the teach might have been expecting would be $$\left\{ ~\cos^{-1}(1/3), ~2\pi - \cos^{-1}(1/3), ~\cos^{-1}(-1/4), ~2\pi - \cos^{-1}(-1/4) ~\right\}.$$

Comment: This answer is correct. I don't know why your teacher marked you down wrong, unless he just wanted you to give the solutions in terms of inverse cosine expressions. One thing I am confused about is why you say you needed to add $\pi$. I don't see how that is relevant at all, especially since you didn't even do that in your calculations.

Comment: @Accelerator You are misinterpreting the OP's posting.  The OP received the explanation that he should have added $(\pi)$, which implies that the person providing the explanation mis-stated the explanation and intended to say that he should have deducted the angle from $(2\pi)$.

Comment: @user2661923  I agree that the OP solved the problem correctly.  However, the range of the arccosine function is $[0, \pi]$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig +1: Nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos x=1/3$ gives you the general solution as $x=2n\pi\pm\cos^{-1}(1/3), n\in\mathbb Z$. For $n=0$, it gives $x=\pm1.231$ as principal solution. For $x\in[0,2\pi)$, $n=0$ and $1$ give the same values you obtained, which shows that your solution is correct.